# string evaluation in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
#DICE GAME

dir=$HOME/Desktop/SCHOOL/COMPUTERGEBRUIK/werkcolleges/oefeningenreeks2/hulpbestanden/bloemblaadjes.txt
echo $dir

MAX=$(wc -l < $dir)  # amount of lines in bloemblaadjes.txt
echo "$MAX"
num=$(( RANDOM % $MAX + 1)) # Random number between 1 and max
echo $num
RESULT=$(head -n $num $dir | tail -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f1,2,3,4,5) 
# first five numbers of       selected line
CORRECT=$(head -n $num $dir | tail -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f6) 
# last number of selected line         =       correct answer
echo $CORRECT
echo "Result:  $RESULT" # showing the person who plays the game what the result are
echo -e "Give the answer: \c" # player needs to give the correct answer
read ANS

if [ "$ANS" = "$CORRECT" ]
then
echo "COOORRECT!"
else
echo "the correct answer is $CORRECT, better luck next time!"
fi
```

In this program, i select a random line from a file and. those lines contain 6 numbers, the first 5 numbers are a result of a dice throw and the other number is the answer. there seems to be something wrong with my if statement: when i run the script in terminal and give the correct answer, it always displays " better luck next time " so the first part of the echo is not displayed. Anyone who can help ?

Comment: Your input file has DOS newlines.

Comment: `dos2unix inputFile`. Good luck.